# jsoup get an element from table header

Tags: jsoup

```
<th "data-next="/?operator=comcast&from=hbo#guide" >
<a href="/hbo/" title="HBO">
  <div>
    <img src="//comcast.com/channel_logo/hbo.png?0">
  </div>
  <span>HBO</span>
</a>
</th>
<th "data-next="/?operator=att&from=fox#guide" >
<a href="/fox/" title="fox">
  <div>
    <img src="//att.com/channel_logo/fox.png?0">
  </div>
  <span>FOX</span>
</a>
</th>
```

I would like to get every link that is in `data-next` so I would like to have:
`/?operator=comcast&from=hbo#guide` and `/?operator=att&from=fox#guide`. But i have a problem with interpretation because I don't know what `data-next` is. It isn't an attribute, or an element so I'm not sure what in jsoup I'm supposed to use. I will appreciate any help

EDITED:

The whole table-header looks like this:

```
<thead class="channelLogos"> 
 <tr>  
  <th "data-next="/?operator=comcast&from=hbo#guide"> <a href="/hbo/" title="HBO"> 
    <div> 
     <img src="//comcast.com/channel_logo/hbo.png?0"> 
    </div> <span>HBO</span> </a> </th>(...)
```

When I've done like this:

```
Elements elts = doc.select("thead.channelLogos th")
for(Element elt : elts) {
   System.out.println(elt.absUrl("data-next"));
}//elts stores th elements but doesn't print anything
```

But like this:

```
Elements elts = doc.select("thead.logaStacji th[data-next]");
```

`elts` is empty (size=`0`)

Comment: There's a double quote before `data-next`. This is why there nothing print. Try to remove this erroneous character.

Comment: but this is exactly how it looks like in the source code of this web page, so it might be a bug. In that case should I use something like `replace()`/`substring()` to fix it by myself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String html = loadHTML(...);

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements elts = doc.select("th[data-next]");

for(Element elt : elts) {
    // Get absolute url stored in data-next attribute
    System.out.println(elt.absUrl("data-next"));
}
```

Comment: I've put an answer to my post, it seems that I'm doing something wrong.